# Hydrogen sulfide and sodium carbonate reaction

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base, home-experiment

What is formed in the reaction between hydrogen sulfide and aqueous sodium carbonate? My guesses are sodium sulfite and/or sodium hydrogen sulfite. However, the equations don't seem to balance properly whenever I try to do it. For example:

$$\ce{H2S(g) + Na2CO3(aq) -> Na2SO3(aq) + H2(g)}$$

It seems quite strange that hydrogen gas would be produced in this kind of reaction. Whatever I do, I end up with a bunch of hydrogen atoms that can't combine with any oxygen, and I'm sure I'm missing something.

Comment: When an equation wouldn't balance at all, this is a subtle hint that something is _really_ wrong with it. Where would carbon go, what do you think?

Comment: To whoever downvoted, can you please explain what's wrong with the question? Otherwise, I can't fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual reaction is [given here](http://chemiday.com/en/reaction/3-1-0-11311).

$$\ce{H2S + Na2CO3 → NaHS + NaHCO3}$$

Conditions:

> Hydrogen sulfide react with sodium carbonate to produce sodium bisulfide and sodium bicarbonate. Hydrogen sulfide should be saturated solution.

While writing a reaction, you must balance the charges and atoms. In your proposed reaction, where did the carbon go? Indeed, the carbon from sodium carbonate gets converted in the form of sodium bicarbonate.

Comment: Do not forget to vetify that the reaction is thermodynamically favored.  Among the acids --hydrogen sulfide on the left, bicarbonate ion on the right -- the weaker acid is favored.  We can verify by looking up dissociation constants that bicarbonate ion is in fact the weaker acid here.